# Setting disk friendly name is reset after reboot

Tags: windows, powershell, disk

I am setting the disk's friendly name using set-physicaldisk however I've noticed that rebooting the machine resets the friendly name.

For instance, I've performed

```
set-physicaldisk -UniqueId myId -NewFriendlyName newName
```

and this sets the friendly name.

If I then restart my computer the friendly name of the disk is reverted back to the original value and not `newName`.

Has anyone noticed this issue and is there a way to set the friendly name/device name for the disk and that it persists on reboot?

Thanks

Comment: Please include the whole command you are issuing in the question

Comment: I've updated the details in the question